# Some time post request takes query string angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Some time post request takes query string i.e `localhost/?password=123456` Don't know why do we need to add button `type="button"` or `type="submit"` please suggest thanks

```
<form name="login" novalidate>
   <div class="row">
      <input type="text" required name="email" id="username" ng-model="email" class="with-border" autofocus=true auto-focus>
   </div>
   <div>
      <input type="password" required name="password" id="password" ng-model="password" class="with-border" >
   </div>
   <a class="pull-left recover-password f-pass-valign" href="#!/forgotpassword">Forgot password?</a>
   <div class="form-group">
      <button ng-click="login(user.email, password)" type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Login</button>               
   </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Instead of calling `login(...)` on `ng-click`, call it on `ng-submit` on the form.

Comment: Anything else that need to replace rather than  ng-click to ng-submit ??

Comment: Try setting `method="post"` on the form tag.

Comment: I am confused which one is opt should i use ng-submit into form or use post as method please guide @31piy

Comment: @Jacob check out this https://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_ng-submit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<form name="login" novalidate method="post">
            <div class="row">
                <input type="text" required name="email" id="username" ng-model="email" class="with-border" autofocus=true auto-focus>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="password" required name="password" id="password" ng-model="password" class="with-border" >
            </div> 
            <a class="pull-left recover-password f-pass-valign" href="#!/forgotpassword">Forgot password?</a>
            <div class="form-group">
              <button ng-click="login(user.email, password)" class="btn btn-danger">Login</button>               
            </div>

        </form>
```

use method as post if you setup button type button then it will work on button click only